# Unity crashes on iPhone at GetCloudProjectId()

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I have a Unity project and am building for iPhone.

When the app starts, it is open for about 1 second before it crashes and **GetCloudProjectId()** is highlighted in the Xcode debug window.

The project uses Unity Services In-App Purchasing so it needs a cloud project id. I can see in the Services settings that is set correctly.

I have tried:

- Unlinking and linking the project again - [using this guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAnalyticsMismatchedProjectId.html)
- Copied the project settings into an empty unity project - also crashed at GetCloudProjectId()

Is there some configuration I forgot to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Info.plist, the UnityCloudProjectID was missing.
I added it manually and this fixed it.